# login failed for user 'sa'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452) in sql 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use windows 7 ultimate. I can login with windows authentication mode but SQL authentication with user `sa` doesn't work. `sa` user is enabled. So what do I do?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Go to `Start` > `Programs` > `Microsoft SQL Server` > `Enterprise Manager`

Right-click the SQL Server instance name > Select `Properties` from the context menu > Select `Security` node in left navigation bar

Under Authentication section, select `SQL Server and Windows Authentication`

**Note**: The server must be stopped and re-started before this will take effect

[Error 18452 (not associated with a trusted sql server connection)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/48ee6a1b-9aad-48a6-90e4-b8f4b93d0107)

Answer (score 33):

Login with windows authentication mode and fist of all make sure that the `sa` authentication is enabled in the server, I am using `SQL Server Management Studio`, so I will show you how to do this there.

Right click on the server and click on Properties.

[image]

Now go to the Security section and select the option `SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode`

[image]

Once that is done, click OK. And then enable the `sa` login.

Go to your server, click on Security and then Logins, right click on `sa` and then click on Properties.

[image]

Now go tot Status and then select Enabled under Login. Then, click OK.

Now we can restart the SQLExpress, or the SQL you are using. Go to Services and Select the SQL Server and then click on Restart. Now open the SQL Server Management Studio and you should be able to login as `sa` user.

Answer (score 18):

1. Click on Start menu > Programs > Microsoft Sql Server > Configuration Tools
2. Select Sql Server Surface Area Configuration.
3. Now click on Surface Area configuration for services and connections
4. On the left pane of pop up window click on Remote Connections and Select Local and Remote connections radio button.
5. Select Using both TCP/IP and named pipes radio button.
6. click on apply and ok.

Now when try to connect to sql server using sql username and password u'll get the error mentioned below

Cannot connect to SQLEXPRESS.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'username'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)
ation 
To fix this error follow steps mentioned below

1. connect to sql server using window authentication.
2. Now right click on your server name at the top in left pane and select properties.
3. Click on security and select sql server and windows authentication mode radio button.
4. Click on OK.
5. restart sql server servive by right clicking on server name and select restart.

Now your problem should be fixed and u'll be able to connect using sql server username and password.

Have fun.
Ateev Gupta

Answer (score 12):

1. First make sure `sa` is enabled
2. Change the authontication mode to mixed mode (Window and SQL authentication)
3. Stop your SQL Server
4. Restart your SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to services.msc from run prompt.
2. Restart the services of SQL server(MSSQLSERVER)
3. Restart the services of SQL server(SQLEXPRESS)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the very same error when I was trying to connect to my SQL Server 2014 instance using `sa` user using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). I was facing this error even when security settings for `sa` user was all good and SQL authentication mode was enabled on the SQL Server instance.

Finally, the issue turned out to be that `Named Pipes` protocol was disabled. Here is how you can enable it:

Open SQL Server Configuration Manager application from start menu. Now, enable `Named Pipes` protocol for both `Client Protocols` and `Protocols for <SQL Server Instance Name>` nodes as shown in the snapshot below:

[image]

**Note**: Make sure you restart the SQL Server instance after making changes.

**P.S.** I'm not very sure but there is a possibility that the `Named Pipes` enabling was required under only one of the two nodes that I've advised. So you can try it one after the other to reach to a more precise solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in same problem for many hours. I tried everything found on internet.

At last, I figured out a surprising solution : I had missed `\SQLEXPRESS` part of the Server name: `MY-COMPUTER-NAME\SQLEXPRESS`

I hope this helps someone who is stuck in similar kind of problem.