# SQL Server authentication is not working from REMOTE

Tags: sql-server, networking, amazon-ec2

I am trying to access a SQL Server hosted on an EC2 instance from my local system. Though I am able to access it within the server using SQL Server authentication, username and password, I am not able to do the same from my local system.

The only change I am doing while accessing it from my local system is to replace the server name with its public DNS.

- On the server: `ServerName\SQLEXPRESS`
- On the local system: `DNS\SQLEXPRESS,1433`

I have also opened the port 1433 in the inbound rules of AWS and in windows firewall as well.

The exact error is as follows:

> Login failed for user 'sa' (Microsoft SQL Server: Error 18456)

Any help/discussion to resolve this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Deleted my answer because I should have deduced from your question that its not a networking issue.  Maybe this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583605/login-failed-for-user-sa-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server) helps.  It basically discusses making sure the authentication is set to ""SQL Server and Windows Authentication".  Sorry, can't help more :/

Comment: Two things come to mind: (1) Have you confirmed on the SQL Server in EC2, using SQL Configuration Manager, that the TCP protocol is actually enabled in the Server Protocols? It could be that it only has Shared Memory and/or Named Pipes protocols enabled. (2) Have you confirmed that the TCP protocol is configured to listen on port 1433? It could be running on a custom port.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help @AlwaysLearning. I had the TCP protocol enabled. But they were listening on dynamic ports. So, I made them to listen on 1434 (For some reason, I am not able to make them listen on 1433). Then, I could successfully connect from my local using the server name as: SERVER_NAME\SQLEXPRESS,1434. Please post your comment as an answer, so that I can accept that. Also, I can use the same server name while connecting from .NET app as well, right?