# How to connect Netbeans to microsoft sql server on mac

Tags: java, sql-server, docker, mssql-jdbc

does anybody know how to connnect netbeans to a microsoft sql server on mac. I am currently running sql server for linux in docker for all my school tasks on win sql.

We got drivers for microsoft sql database and I have add them in netbeans(8.2) but I dont know how to connect my azure data studio (or server that i run on docker) to my aplication. Everybody else is on wins and that driver works great with netbeans (8.2) and ssms.

Does any of you know how to fix my problem or do I need to run wins for this to work.

Ty

edit:
this is error log that I get when I run solution
https://pastebin.pl/view/ab3472d4

Comment: Q: Are you talking about a JDBC connection to MSSQL  in your Java app?  Or a JDBC connection to MSSQL from the NetBeans IDE?  Are you talking about a local instances of MSSQL (SQL Server Express), an MSSQL server, or Azure SQL Database?  Assuming Netbeans IDE => MSSQL, look here: https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/sql-jdbc-netbeans.rst

Comment: I am not sure, i am new to all this... i need to save thing that i create in java app in mssql database.. i am need to do it on local instance, on localhost

Comment: I will try that and see if that works.. ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your question:**

How to connect Netbeans to Microsoft SQL Server on Mac

**Your stack traceback:**

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'. ClientConnectionId:99bbec4b-d242-485c-a5b7-3055277b7d0f
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:254)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:258)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:104)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4772)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3581)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:81)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3541)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7240) ...
        at hr.algebra.dal.sql.SqlRepository.selectArticles(SqlRepository.java:137)
        at hr.algebra.UploadArticlesPanel.loadModel(UploadArticlesPanel.java:117)
        at hr.algebra.UploadArticlesPanel.init(UploadArticlesPanel.java:106)
        at hr.algebra.UploadArticlesPanel.<init>(UploadArticlesPanel.java:30)
        at hr.algebra.Zadatak01.configurePanels(Zadatak01.java:91)
        at hr.algebra.Zadatak01.<init>(Zadatak01.java:22)
        at hr.algebra.Zadatak01$1.run(Zadatak01.java:81)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756) ...
```

**Your *REAL* question:**

Q: Why is my JDBC app failing with a `Login failed for user 'sa'` error?

A: Make sure your database is configured for [SQL Server Authentication](https://www.virtual-dba.com/differences-windows-sql-server-authentication/), and *NOT* "Windows Authentication", and make sure the "sa" password is correct.

These links give additional information:

- [login failed for user 'sa'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452) in sql 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583605)
- [Troubleshooting Microsoft SQL Server Error 18456](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/troubleshooting-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-login-failed-user/)

This link also discusses Linux/Docker specific issues:

- https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/506