# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() when connecting from Apache to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, sqlsrv

I am using Apache server version 2.4 and PHP version 8.2. I want to connect to SQL Server but get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> mssql_connect()  in D:\Apache24\htdocs\mcd\configsql.php:6 Stack
> trace: #0 {main} thrown  in D:\Apache24\htdocs\mcd\configsql.php on
> line 6

I have added this `extension` to `D:\Apache24\php\php.ini`:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll
```

The extension has also been installed correctly and appears in `phpinfo()`, like this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/9UI5tQM6gFGl

I have also used the `sqlsrv_connect()` function like this:

```
<?php
$myServer = "pcserver";
$myUser = "username";
$myPass = "password";
$myDB = "dbus";
$dbhandle = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
$selected = sqlsrv_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle) or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");
```

But got the error below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: sqlsrv_connect() expects at
> most 2 arguments, 3 given in D:\Apache24\htdocs\mcd\configsql.php:6
> Stack trace: #0 D:\Apache24\htdocs\mcd\configsql.php(6):
> sqlsrv_connect('pcserver', 'username', 'password') #1 {main} thrown in
> D:\Apache24\htdocs\mcd\configsql.php on line 6

I have tried following the `sqlsrv_connect` documentation on this link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php.

I tried using a connection with Windows authentication until the username and password were like this:

```
<?php
$serverName = "192.168.0.1"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"mydbname", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

The code does not get results but gets the following error: https://prnt.sc/HQyaawaNh5x0

Comment: I've tried deleting the `sqlsrv_select_db()` function, but it still gives an error. I want to update this code to the latest. @Zhorov

Comment: Have you tried reading the [sqlsrv_connect documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) to see how it should be used?

Comment: I have tried it and got this error https://prnt.sc/QkQguS-xVVA9 @AlwaysLearning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `mssql_connect()` and `mssql_select_db()` are part of the old and unsupported `mssql` PHP extension. If you want to connect to SQL Server instance using PHP Driver for SQL Server you need to use `sqlsrv_connect()`, which replaces both functions. There is no `sqlsrv_select_db()` function as part of the PHP Driver for SQL Server and changing the prefix `mssql` in the functions names with `sqlsrv` is not an option.

The `sqlsrv_connect()` expects two parameters - `$serverName` (a string specifying the name of the server to which a connection is being established) and `$connectionInfo` (an associative array that contains connection attributes). The database in use is usually the first connection option. If you want to connect using SQL authentication, include username and password of the SQL Server login as additional connection options and ensure that your current SQL Server instance uses both SQL and Windows authentication:

```
<?php

// Connect to SQL Server instance using SQL authentication
$myServer = "pcserver";
$myUser   = "username";
$myPass   = "password";
$myDB     = "dbus";
$options  = array(
    "Database" => $myDB,
    "UID"      => $myUser,
    "PWD"      => $myPass
);
$dbhandle = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, $options) or die ("Couldn't connect to SQL Server");

// Connect to SQL Server instance using Windows authentication
$myServer = "pcserver";
$myUser   = "username";
$myPass   = "password";
$myDB     = "dbus";
$options  = array(
    "Database" => $myDB
);
$dbhandle = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, $options) or die ("Couldn't connect to SQL Server");

?>
```

Comment: I've tried it and got this error https://prnt.sc/QkQguS-xVVA9 @Zhorov

Comment: Yes, I've enabled it https://prnt.sc/byi6AMenCIf2 @Zhorov

Comment: How is it different from an administrator? I logged into SSMS using Windows authentication. I've tried using the `sa` username and password but it still doesn't work. @Zhorov

Comment: My server doesn't use a domain. I have tried using Windows authentication, and it still gives the same error. This is the status of my sa account https://prnt.sc/7FMFpHbEwoP6 @Zhorov

Comment: I'm sure I'm using the correct credentials. In fact, I have rewritten my password in Notepad and moved it to `sa` password https://prnt.sc/webt-fEjLBp5. Yes, I use SQL authentication as I showed in my question above, and I follow the PHP documentation about `sqlsrv_connect` after I run the error like this https://prnt.sc/HQyaawaNh5x0 @Zhorov

Comment: I've edited my question above. And give a new error according to the instructions you have given. @Zhorov

Comment: @Rudi, you need to set the SQL Server instance to use both SQL and Windows authentication. A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583605/login-failed-for-user-sa-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server). Yor current code seems correct. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for providing the information. It worked after I restarted my server. @Zhorov